# PHP Like Button Problems

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a like button for posts on my website.

PHP for like query (d_db_update is

```
function d_db_update($string) { 
    return mysql_query($string);
}
```

)

```
if($_GET['like']) {
  $like = d_db_update("UPDATE posts set post_rating = post_rating+1 WHERE post_id = {$_GET['like']}");
}
```

Button

```
 <form action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}&like={$posts_row['post_id']}' method='get'>
 <p align='left'>{$posts_row['post_rating']} 
 <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like' /></p>
 </form>
```

What can I do to fix it/make it work?

Comment: But... what's the problem?

Comment: Besides your perfectly described problem, you might consider using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid people like me making those boring comments about [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

Use below form with a hidden input it solve your problem.

```
<form action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' method='get'>
  <p align='left'>{$posts_row['post_rating']} 
  <input type='hidden' name='like' value='{$posts_row['post_id']}' />
  <input type='submit' value='Like' /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using your form action wrong.. if you are using `get method` than **there is not need to use the form**..

try this..

`<a href='yourpage.php?like=<?php echo $post_id ?>'>Like</a>`

Comment: So you say forms using GET are useless?

Comment: @DamienPirsy **no not at all** but in this case may be there should be **many like buttons**.. so using form for every like button (I would not suggest it) :-)....

Comment: yes i do agree using form is not feasible thats why i suggested othe roption i.e. anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

You can not write PHP variables using `{}`. You need to `echo` them out.

```
<form action='' method='get'>
<p align='left'><?php echo $posts_row['post_rating'] ?>
<input type='hidden' name='like' value='<?php echo $posts_row["post_id"] ?>' />
<input type='submit' value='Like' /></p>
</form>
```

Edit--

You were not returning the post id correctly, I made the changes, also there is no need to provide any action as it will be self only.

Comment: I don't think so :) If he forget this expression, he won't do nothing:) Then If he don't know nothing, how can he write `{}` these. I think there is no problem unless he didn't say other things.

Comment: My whole page a.k.a every page is always in php i have to leave php to get the html.

Answer (score 0):

your submit button name and like variable which you have used in action url are the same , and you used get method in method of form.So, you need to change the submit button name.

or

you can do it without using form only on button click try below code

```
 <input type='button' name='like' value='Like' onclick="location.href='yourpage.php?like=<?php echo $post_id ?>'" />
```

Comment: this should be `window.location.href` instead of `location.href` .. :)